# Windows is normal so RO will run

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm running a Vue app on localhost:8080 on Google Chrome and whenever I refresh the page I see:

`window is normal so RO will run!`

followed by:

`RO disabled for this window`

Logged automatically to my console.

I've googled this and the only results seem to be related to Windows OS, but I'm on a Mac if that's relevant.

Why are these console logs appearing?

EDIT:

The following functions which create the log messages are seemingly generated by WebPack. It seems to be related to Chrome because the messages do not appear when running in Firefox.

This function in `index.js` seems to throw the first log:

```
function initRo() {
    if (problematicChromeVersion === undefined) {
        problematicChromeVersion = isProblematicChromeVersion();
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $(document)
            .ready(function () {
                return utils.getCurrentWindow()
                    .then((windowResp) => {
                        if (windowResp.window.type !== 'normal') {
                            throw(`window is ${windowResp.window.type} so RO wont run!`)
                        }
                        console.log(`window is ${windowResp.window.type} so RO will run!`);
                        isRoAllowedOnPage = windowResp.isAllowed;
                        if (!isRoAllowedOnPage) {
                            throw DISABLED_RO_MSG;
                        }
                    })
                    .then(() => initExtension(isRoAllowedOnPage))
                    .then(() => initButtons())
                    .then(() => initLoader(isRoAllowedOnPage))
                    .then(() => initIFrame())
                    .then(() => resolve())
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    })
            });
    });
}
```

And this function throws the second log message:

```
function chromeOnChangeListener(request, sender, response) {
    if (request.type === 'onUpdated' && tabUrl !== request.tabUrl) {
        tabUrl = request.tabUrl || tabUrl;
        resolveWhenReady.then(function () {
            pageChanged();
        }).catch(err => {
            if (err === DISABLED_RO_MSG) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                console.error(err);
            }
        })
    }

    if (request.type === 'open') {
        if (EXTENSION_ELEMENT && !(EXTENSION_ELEMENT.hasClass(TWENTY_PCT_CLASS) || EXTENSION_ELEMENT.hasClass(EIGHTY_PCT_CLASS))) {
            buttonActions.shrink(true);
        }
        else if (!EXTENSION_ELEMENT && !isRoAllowedOnPage) {
            isRoAllowedOnPage = true;
            openFromClosed(request.tabUrl);
        }
    }

    if (request.type === 'browserIconClicked') {
        if (EXTENSION_ELEMENT) {
            if (EXTENSION_ELEMENT.hasClass(MINIMIZED_CLASS)) {
                buttonActions.shrink(true);
            }
            else {
                buttonActions.minimize(true);
            }
        }
        else {
            //EXTENSION_ELEMENT doesn't exist, so we'll need to open from closed state.
            isRoAllowedOnPage = true;
            openFromClosed(request.tabUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doubtful that its windows - please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I'm not sure how to in this case, I didn't write write the console logging line of code, it seems to be coming from somewhere within webpack

Comment: Anything logged to your console will also include a link (right-hand side) to the line of code that produced it. Follow that link

Comment: Updated to the best of my ability

Comment: I guarantee that the message is not coming from Webpack but from something else that it is bundling. For one, Webpack does **not** use jQuery

Comment: I'm sure that is correct, I'm out of my depth here. How would recommend that I explore this further to find where this code lives. I can't seem to find the `index.js` that it seems to live in

Comment: It looks to be an extension

Comment: You are correct @DanielA.White, I was able to trace it to a specific extension thanks to your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a message logged from the ZoomInfo Reach Out (RO) Chrome extension. It is in fact logged on every single webpage, and is not specific to Vue. Removing the extension will get rid of these messages.